# Python, load shared-object in-place

Tags: python, setup.py, dynamic-loading

I have some C code, and a Python (3.8) interface to it, I can install this shared object (into `/usr/local/...` on Linux) and run Python scripts against it, and that all works fine.

But I would like to load that `.so` file *before* installing it so I can run some tests against it.  As I understand it, `LD_LOAD_PATH` is my friend, but how can I get the build directory?  In my case, the `.so` is built in

```
build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/maxmodnb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

so is there some simple way to get the `lib.linux-x86_64-3.8`?

Possibly I'm asking the wrong question: is there a simple way to load this file before install?

[edit]

Of course `LD_LOAD_PATH` has nothing to do with it, one just adds that directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an easy way, but this reverse-engineered script seems to do the trick:

```py
from sys import platform, version_info
from os import uname

print(
    'lib.%s-%s-%i.%i' % (
        platform,
        uname()[4],
        version_info[0],
        version_info[1]
    )
)
```

which gives

```sh
$ python python-so-dir.py 
lib.linux2-x86_64-2.7
$ python3 python-so-dir.py 
lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
```

as expected.